# Perl. print  &lt;&gt;

Tags: perl

Здравствуйте.
Вопрос задан исключительно с целью понять как думает Perl (ведь чтобы думать на Perl надо иметь представление о том, как думает он) увидев в коде

```
print <>;
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему эта команда выполняется таким образом:
Можно вводить сколько угодно строк в консоли, но они будут выведены только после нажатия `ctrl+break` ?
В других языках аналогичные конструкции обычно просто приводят к выводу введенной строки.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

По тому, что `print` ожидает списочный контекст `(perldoc -f print)`,и `<>` в списочном контексте работает именно таким вот чудесным образом, возвращает список. Если есть желание выводить данные сразу, то пользуйтесь скалярным контекстом:

```
while (<>) {
  print;
}
```

или более лаконичной записью

```
print while <>;
```

или как-то так:

```
my $scalar = <>;
print $scalar;
```

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь понятно.

Comment: print scalar <>;